# jQuery clicked statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This does not work for me. I am trying to toggleClass to few elements when clicking on any of these 3 elements. Any suggestion?

```
if (  ($("#id-one").click) || ($("#id-two").click) || ($("#id-three").click)  ) {

        //do something here
}
```

Comment: Yes, open your console (it says you have a syntax error and you're missing a parenthesis)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's important to [read the documentation of the tools you're using](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Nowhere in that documentation will use see `click` used like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Turns out, before edition, the original code was `if ( ($("#id-one").click) || ($("#id-two").click) || ($("#id-three.click) ) {`. It's missing _both_ a `"` and a `)`.

Comment: @JeremyThille: What a mess. :-)

Comment: XD I know right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind event handler, You can use [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) which is a shorthand for `.on( "click", handler )`

```
$("#id-one,#id-two,#id-three").click(function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Or, You can assign a common class then use [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to attach event handler

Answer (score 2):

The jquery selector is the same as a css selector, so target multiple elements like so

```
$("#id-one, #id-two, #id-three").on('click', function() {
    //do something here
})
```

you can then target the individual element which was clicked using `$(this)`

Comment: ...alternatively, use a class

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a common class to all the elements for which you want to run the same code on `click` function. Say, the class name you add to all these element is `test` then, your HTML could be something like:

```
<div id='id-one' class='test'></div>
<div id='id-two' class='test'></div>
<div id='id-three' class='test'></div>
```

And your JQuery code could be like:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('someClass');
});
```

This approach is really flexible and easy to understand as you just need to change the HTML side bu adding `test` class to your elements without having to change the `jquery` code every time when you require click event on that element. Also, this works great when you do not have `id` value for the element where you want to associate a `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **jQuery** library you have to use [toggleClass()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp) Method. If you are using JavaScript you can use the *toggle()* Method `element.classList.toggle("yourclass");`

```js
$("#id-one, #id-two, #id-three").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
})
```

```css
.on {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="id-one">
id one
</button>
<button id="id-two">
id two
</button>
<button id="id-three">
id three
</button>
```